# Fazer include de arquivos css e js com vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Estou estudando a implementação de laravel e vuejs e utilizando como template o admin lte. Minha dúvida é: no index.html do vuejs, eu coloco todos os arquivos base de css e js. Mas e quando a página requer uma arquivo específico de css e ou de js, como fazer esse include no component do vuejs? Antes eu estava fazendo tudo em um local só, agora separei o backend do frontend. Nem sempre um arquivo js vai ter um export, ainda mais nesses casos de templates da web. Além do mais, também há a necessidade de importar arquivos css para páginas específicas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar o `require` Baseado em [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/)

Por exemplo ao importar o `bootstrap` você simplesmente instala-o e puxa com require.

```
require('bootstrap');
```

para puxar o css

```
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Para puxar qualquer outro arquivo, basta subir na pasta raiz dos componentes (src) e procurar...

```
require('./css/style.css');
```

Você pode usar loaders como css-loader e style-loader, basta instalar e adicionar o url-loader

```
{
   test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
   loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

Para importar `js`, ainda recomendo usar o `import`, basta declarar uma classe e usa-la na página com o new, exemplo...

**classe.js**

```
export class Classe{

    constructor(nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

**main.js**

```
import {Classe} from './classe';
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    nome : new Classe('stackOverflow')
}
```

Comment: Mas e quando é um js de algum template? Exemplo, estou usando o adminlte como testes, algumas páginas requerem js específicos mas que não retornam necessariamente uma classe mas possuem várias funções para determinada coisa naquela página. Como importar esse tipo de js?

Comment: Bom, nunca tentei com js inline, mas require não funcionaria?

Comment: Felipe, as vezes que tentei não deu certo. Acabo carregando TODOS os css e js no index do vue, o que acaba gerando um carregamento extra desnecessário na aplicação.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, mas caso esteja usando o Webpack é necessário algumas configurações para exportar js externo, se não me engano, você precisa de loaders como https://webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/ e também gerenciar a distribuição de chunks para as páginas que realmente irão usar determinados arquivos, eliminando assim o carregamento de todos de uma só vez.